# Set the Assembly Version and get it by reflection - all the time version 1.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I had a problem with setting properly the Assembly version and then obtaining it by the reflection. I found a workaround, but I am still curious why it behaves like this...

I have a Class Library project, I am loading it and reading the version by following code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
var version= assembly.GetName().Version;
```

And I get a good result:

```
assembly {AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
version  "1.0.0.0"
```

But now I have changed in the Class Library project the Assembly version and File version fields to the value of 2.0.0.0. I have compiled it and I have run IL DASM to compare both libraries.

Everywhere in IL DASM, i.e. in Main Window, in Manifest, in Metainfo I have seen that my new library have version 2.0.0.0 and the pervious library have 1.0.0.0, so I was happy that everything was correct.

But then I went back to my application, I have loaded the assembly with version 2.0.0.0, and this is the result:

```
assembly {AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
version  "1.0.0.0"
```

So the reflection does not return to me the good version value.
The workaround is to use the FileVersionInfo class:

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assemblyName).FileVersion;
```

Now I get the proper result.

My questions are: what else I need to change in my Class Library Project to be able to retrieve a good version by the reflection mechanism? Why IL DASM is showing a proper version and reflection is not? I always thought that IL DASM under the hood utilize the reflection, but now it seems to me s

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: ildasm does not use reflection; it uses a low-level IL parser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I have managed to solve it. The problem was with the loading method from the Assembly class.

I was using the Assembly.LoadFrom with the full path to the DLL as argument. I have realized that when I was loading my library with version 2.0.0.0 the Assembly.LoadFrom was returning my first library, I have verified it by the CodeBase property which was pointing to the location of library version 1.0.0.0 and not 2.0.0.0.

I have change my loading code to Assembly.LoadFile, now it is working properly.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
```